# NodeJS, Redis and MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, redis, memcached

Please has anyone ever used `NodeJS` + `Redis` + `MySQL`
The goal is to have NodeJS fetch data from Redis and only reach MySQL if data not found, also update `MySQL` back with the data.

Then how can i run relational request from Redis knowing its a `NoSQL` `in-memory DB`

I have read that Redis is better than `Memcached` and it seems to be faster so I wanted to try it out but it seems all tutorial i can lay my hands on are just `PHP` based.

Currently I use NodeJs + MySQL as below (example) :

```
var d = new Date();
var date = d.getFullYear() + '-' + paddnum(Math.round(d.getMonth() + 1)) + '-' + paddnum(d.getDate()) + ' ' + paddnum(d.getHours()) + ':' + paddnum(d.getMinutes()) + ':' + paddnum(d.getSeconds());

var query = `INSERT INTO comments (COMMENT, POSTID)
                        VALUES ('{"author":"` + data.userid + `", "comment": "` + data.comment + `", "time":"` + date + `"}', ` + data.postid + `)
                        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                            COMMENT = CONCAT(COMMENT, ',{"author":"` + data.userid + `", "comment": "` + data.comment + `", "time":"` + date + `"}'),
                            POSTID = ` + data.postid;
//console.log(query);
connection.query(query,
    function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            return err;
        }
        return results;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure what you really need, but based on question you need code and module that will work between nodejs code and MySQL db.
You can use this module for redis operation
git://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis.git

Now all what you need is connect to redis, fill the data in and then on user request check redis->if found return data if not do db queries. Or vice versa.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks seems to be the way forward and its very okay, but what i am confused about now is if i want to do relational query (MULTIPLE JOINS) with redis, thanks again

Comment: Well...As far as i know redis doent have JOIN's functionality. It just basically pub/sub system. So it just stores values inside and give it back. But from my experience it's very good to hold some large objects with data and get it back. For example you can save MySQL result to redis and later just get this result from redis multiple times. That approach can save a lot of time.  Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks alot, after mutiple digging i realize for data requiring RELATIONS all i have to do i create VIEW in MYSQL and save its data in REDIS so the data in request from REDIS will just be VIEWS which goes without relationship